# Обернуть тег в ссылку по названию из объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем вот такой вот объект со свойствами в виде заголовков и ссылок:

```
var links = {"Title1": "link1",
             "Title2": "link2",
             "Title3": "link3"
             };
```

На странице находится маркированный список вот такого вида:

```
<ul class="list">
<li><b>12:00</b> <h3>Title1</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
<li><b>13:00</b> <h3>Title2</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
<li><b>14:00</b> <h3>Title3</h3></li>
</ul>
```

Возможно ли отыскать совпадение по заголовкам и добавить ссылку именно в этот пункт списка? Буду благодарен за пример, хотя бы определения нужного пункта.

Конечный результат:

```
<ul class="list">
<li><b>12:00</b> <h3>Title1</h3> <i>Some text</i> <a href="link1" title="Title1">Read more</a></li>
<li><b>13:00</b> <h3>Title2</h3> <i>Some text</i> <a href="link2" title="Title2">Read more</a></li>
<li><b>14:00</b> <h3>Title3</h3> <a href="link3" title="Title3">Read more</a></li>
</ul>
```

Или, в крайнем случае, обернуть заголовок в ссылку.

Comment: да, это возможно

Comment: вопрос можно закрывать )

Comment: @Grundy если поделитесь примером или укажите что мне потребуется для определения пункта, буду весьма признателен.

Comment: >> 1к репутации >> Вопрос начинающего по js. Ну это так, неважно... Это реально и вполне осуществимо. Всё, что нужно знать, это как работать с объектами в js и как искать элементы по DOM. Совпадения ищутся при помощи равенства. Вот и всё... Но скорее всего скоро такую легкую задачку тебе напишут в ответы. Но реально, ты мог бы и сам просто покапаться в гугле и немного подучить язык, и написать сам. Минут 30 хватило бы.

Comment: @VostokSisters https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3922/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Замечание дельное. Пример оказался предельно прост. А комментарий в общем-то дает направления к размышлению. Мне 30 минут не хватило, возможно из-за поисков более сложных путей, а оказалось все куда проще.

Comment: @VostokSisters 1k репутации собрано из других направлений, а по JS вопросы задаю больше в образовательных целях. Спасибо за направления.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, да я бегло посмотрел профиль, в топовых тегах конкретно веб вроде бы.

Comment: @VostokSisters в топе CSS и HTML

Comment: @Alexey, ну и расскажи мне, как можно вариться в css и html, но не практиковаться в js? Я реально не могу представить это. Мне кажется это неразрывные три вещи...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var links = {
  "Title1": "link1",
  "Title2": "link2",
  "Title3": "link3"
};

var list = $('.list');

for (var item in links) { 
  var el = list.find('h3:contains("' + item + '")');
  el.closest('li').append(' <a href="' + links[item] + '" title="' + item + '">Read more</a>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><b>12:00</b>
    <h3>Title1</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
  <li><b>13:00</b>
    <h3>Title2</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
  <li><b>14:00</b>
    <h3>Title3</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[find](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)** - Осуществляет поиск элементов внутри уже выбранных элементов.

**[contains](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)** - Соответствует элементам, которые содержат строку *text*. Чувствителен к регистру.

**[closest](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)** - Для каждого из выбранных элементов, closest() будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель, и так далее, до начало дерева DOM.

Comment: а как ты хотел там of использовать? он же вроде с обычным объектом не работает?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пример очень просто на вид когда уже готов. Отправлюсь еще раз перечитать все указанные ссылки.

Comment: @Grundy угу....

Answer (score 2):

Логика и десять минут в гугле.
Но меня тут убеждают что надо помогать даже в таких вопросах, поэтому:

```js
let links = {
  "Title1": "link1",
  "Title2": "link2",
  "Title3": "link3"
};

// Ищем все заголовки (h3) в списке
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list h3')).forEach(e => {
  // Если значение заголовка (Title3, например) есть в карте
  if(e.innerText in links){
    // То создаём ссылку с нужными параметрами
    let a = document.createElement('A');
    a.href = links[e.innerText];
    a.innerText = 'Read more';
    // И вставляем её в конец родительского li
    e.parentNode.appendChild(a);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><b>12:00</b><h3>Title1</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
  <li><b>13:00</b><h3>Title2</h3> <i>Some text</i></li>
  <li><b>14:00</b><h3>Something</h3></li>
  <li><b>14:00</b><h3>Title3</h3></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3922/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, чойта?

Comment: ну это к комментарию про гугл )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я не послал в гугл, хотя стоило бы, а дал ответ, читайте внимательно.

Comment: Если укажите на полезные ссылки, которые я мог найти в google, буду признателен. Я всегда, перед тем как задать вопрос ищу решения в сети и пробую все самостоятельно. Даже получив ответ, разбираю его, чтоб все было понятно. Именно для этого такой ресурс и существует. Именно поэтому, на такие же "элементарные" вопросы (с вашей точки зрения) и даю ответы на вопросы других пользователей.